# Discord.py response.json "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable "

Tags: python, discord, steam

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("https:"):
            response = requests.get(f"https://converter.api.dedns.org/" f"{message}")
            steam_id64 = response.json()["data"]["steam_id64"]
            await message.channel.send("Steam ID'niz" %steam_id64)
```

When I send a message with a link, send a request to converter.api.dedns.org and send the "steam_id64" information from the "data" as a response, but I get the following error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vntcrt\PycharmProjects\idsteamdc\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/vntcrt/PycharmProjects/idsteamdc/mainv2.py", line 21, in on_message
    steam_id64 = response.json()["data"]["steam_id64"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

When I run the code below and send a message with a link, it gives the answer I entered as a response, but it gives error in above code

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("https:"):
        await message.channel.send("Steam")
```

When I send a message with a link, I want it to receive the content of message and enter content of the message  to site and send "steam_id64" information in  "data" section from site as a reply.

Comment: `response.json()` is returning `None`.  I'm just guessing here, but perhaps it's because you're not urlencoding the message?

Comment: As a first debugging step, try printing `response.json()` and `response.body` to see what they contain.

Comment: i have printed `response.json()`, in the 'data' section, it contains 'steamid64' information

Comment: Then I don't see how that error can happen...

Comment: `@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    response = requests.get(f"https://converter.api.dedns.org/" f"{message}")


print(response.json())`

when I try to print like this it gives the following error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vntcrt/PycharmProjects/idsteamdc/mainv2.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(response.json())
NameError: name 'response' is not defined`


I wrote a value instead of f"{message} and printed it, then it didn't give an error and it contained 'steam_id64' information in the 'data' section.

Comment: `@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
         response = requests.get(f"https://converter.api.dedns.org/" f"{message}")
         print(response.json())`

i printed it like this it gave the following answer
`{'error': False, 'data': None}`

Comment: I get a request from the site instead of the api and printed it. It contains steamid64, but how can I find its section in html?

Comment: fixed it, thanks for ur help